# Как найти children из clicked элементa

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let car = document.querySelectorAll(".rg--car");
  let s = document.querySelectorAll(".car-speed");
  let carSpped = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
    car[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle("rg--selected");
      if (car[i].classList.contains("rg--selected")) {
       //code here
      }
    });
  }
```

как найти car-speed element из e.target

Answer (score 0):

```
var speed = car[i].querySelector(".car-speed");
// или
var speed = e.target.querySelector(".car-speed");

if (speed) {
  // code
}
```